# ajaxにて他サイトのHTMLを取得

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

ajaxを使って他サイトのHtmlを取得したいのですが、クロスドメインでエラーが起こってしまいます。
jsonpなら取得できるかと思い、試しに下記のコードでやってみたのですが

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://hoge.jp',
    dataType: 'JSONP',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function ({data}) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

とブラウザエラーが表示されました。
cors対応もされていないサイトなので、どうすればいいのかがわかりません。
何か他に対応方法があるのでしょうか？

Comment: 他サイトとありますが、そのサイトはご自身で所有権や管理権限はお持ちですか？

Comment: 自分のサイトではないです。勉強がてらスクレイピングをやってみたいと思っております

Answer (score 2):

ブラウザとjavascriptを用いてAjax通信で、ドメイン外からのデータ取得はサイト側が Access-Control-Allow-Originヘッダでそれを認めない限り、アクセスはできません。
https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTTP/HTTP_access_control

他の方が回答しているようにサーバを用意してのスクレイピングが一般的ですのでそちらを検討お願いします。

Answer (score 0):

サーバーが使えるのかわかりませんが、phpを挟んで取得する方法もありますよ。
http://php.net/manual/ja/function.file-get-contents.php
ちょっとうまくいくかわかりませんが。

Comment: 回答はありがたいのですが、その方法の概要だけでも回答中で説明するようにしてください。外部サイトはURLが変わったりするなど、アクセスできなくなる可能性があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。でもなるべくでしたらjsだけで完結出来ればと思っているのですが、可能でしょうか？